# ALSA REAL TIME AUDIO PROGRAMMING

Tags: alsa

I am trying set external audio interface in Ubuntu  as default so that I can use it in real time audio programming using ALSA. Any help please

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make you make card as default card. Try this [link](http://blog.ostermiller.org/ubuntu-usb-audio/)